# Duplicate php openssl_encrypt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, aes

I'm trying to duplicate PHP string encryption using JavaScript. Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$iv = "1234567890123456";
$key = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
$input = "texttexttexttext";

$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($input, "AES-256-CBC", $key, 0, $iv);

echo $encrypted;
// "ZwY1i+vqP3acszeDiscCTx/R4a6d2AtkcInmN9OTCNE="
```

However, when I try to duplicate it in JavaScript it gives a different ciphertext:

```
var aesjs = require("aes-js");
var base64 = require("js-base64");

var iv = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes("1234567890123456");
var key = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
var text = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes("texttexttexttext");

var aesCbc = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.cbc(key, iv);
var encryptedBytes = aesCbc.encrypt(text);

var b64encoded = base64.Base64.encode(encryptedBytes);

console.log(b64encoded);
// "MTcyLDIsNjAsMTU5LDcxLDEwLDE4Myw4LDE…wyMTIsMjIyLDk3LDEyNCw1MywxNzIsMjIy"
```

I have no clue on how to make it give the same output. Any ideas?

Comment: `MTcyLDIsNjAsMTU5LDcxLDEwLDE4Myw4LDE…` decodes to `172,2,60,159,71,10,183,8,1…`. It looks like `base64.Base64.encode()` encodes the *string representation* of `encryptedBytes`.

What is the output if you try `console.log(encryptedBytes.toString('base64'));`?

Comment: Just an idea: in PHP you use explicitly a 256 bit key. With aesjs the key lengths seems to be determined by the count of bytes/bits from the key variable - in your case it is 16*8 = 128 bits instead of 256.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some things are going wrong:

**First**, the output from the JavaScript code is actually the base64 encoding of the string `172,2,60,159,71,10,183,8,1,…`, not the encoding of the raw byte-buffer. I do not really know how to fix this idiomatically, but by using the `aes.js` hex-encoding utility function, we can convert it to base64:

```
var hex = aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);
var buf = Buffer.from(hex, 'hex');

console.log(buf.toString('base64'));
// rAI8n0cKtwiu1N5hfDWs3g==
```

The **second** problem is that in `aes.js` you are using AES128 encryption (`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` is 128 bits long), but you are using AES256 encryption in the PHP code. We should update the PHP code (or the JS code):

```
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($input, "AES-128-CBC", $key, 0, $iv);
echo $encrypted;
// rAI8n0cKtwiu1N5hfDWs3rPbz0UmvlbW+LJliYox03c=
```

We *almost* have the same output. But wait, the PHP output is twice as long. What happened?

Well, OpenSSL [uses PKCS#7 padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10523/45787). The Javascript code is unpadded however. To fix this, you should use PKCS#7 padding for the javascript text. For this you can just use the [pkcs7](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkcs7) module. Another option is to use AES in counter (CTR) mode instead of CBC mode, if this is an option for you.

This is the PHP code that I have in the end:

```
<?php
$iv = "1234567890123456";
$key = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
$input = "texttexttexttext";
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($input, "AES-128-CBC", $key, 0, $iv);
echo $encrypted;
// output: 'rAI8n0cKtwiu1N5hfDWs3rPbz0UmvlbW+LJliYox03c='
```

And this is the JavaScript code:

```
var aesjs = require("aes-js");
var base64 = require("js-base64");
var pkcs7 = require("pkcs7");

var iv = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes("1234567890123456");
var key = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
var text = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes("texttexttexttext");

var aesCbc = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.cbc(key, iv);
var encryptedBytes = aesCbc.encrypt(pkcs7.pad(text));

var hex = aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);
var buf = Buffer.from(hex, 'hex');

console.log(buf.toString('base64'));
// output: 'rAI8n0cKtwiu1N5hfDWs3rPbz0UmvlbW+LJliYox03c='
```

**PS** I personally prefer using CTR mode, because PKCS#7 implementations sometimes expose [padding oracles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack) which break the encryption. (I checked the mentioned pkcs#7 library which should be good, but [please don't try to implement this yourself](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/152961).)